# Order by one element and return multi properties in the same LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `list`

```
        List<Order> OL = new List<Order>()
        {
            new Order("O-1","P1",200,2),
            new Order("O-2","P1",200,3),
            new Order("O-3","P1",1000,1),
            new Order("O-4","P2",200,2)
        };
```

The **Order** `class` :

```
   class Order
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get { return Price * Quantity; } }

    public Order(string _ID, string _Product, int _Price, int _Quantity)
    {
        ID = _ID;
        Product = _Product;
        Price = _Price;
        Quantity = _Quantity;
    }
    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

So I want to return the **name** and the **counting** (Number of times the product repeated in orders) for each product.

**I tried :**

```
        var P = OL.OrderByDescending(x => x.Product.Count()).Take(2);
        MessageBox.Show(P.ElementAt(0).Product);
```

But just getting the product name, Please any help? and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var groupedProducts = OL.GroupBy(o => o.Product)
                     .Select(g => new { Product = g.Key, Quantity = g.Count() })
                     .OrderByDescending(p => p.Quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by `Product` then sort by `Count()`

```
var P = OL.GroupBy(x => x.Product)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
          .Select(g => new { Product = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```